# using a list as positional index for another list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, database, list

I have two Python lists.

The first list (called `converted`) reported n values (columns) extracted from an Excel file. Each element in the list "converted" contains multiple column values extracted from the Excel file (see the output)

The second list (called `values_index`) contains n values that I want to use as positional index for printing specific elements of the first list from values_index to the end.

```
converted = [a, b, c, d, e, f..]
value_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6..]
```

I want to use `values_index` for extracting the corresponding value in the converted list, from that value to the end. The value index should become the first element of the columns in the converted list. I want to extract the value from `values_index` to the end of the columns.

So, basically `valuex_index` 1 should be coupled with converted a, values index 2 should be couple with converted b and so on. Then I should print from the position to value_index to the end of the column.

Here an example:

```
filelist = os.listdir(path)
filelist = sorted(filelist, key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))
print(filelist)

asps = []

for file in filelist:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        asps.append(df)

print(asps)

speed = []
average = []

for table in asps:
    speed.append(table['Reversal Intensities'].iloc[15:25])
print(speed)
for each in speed:
    np.mean(each)
    average.append(np.mean(each))
print(average)


rev_ind = []
for each in asps:
    rev_ind.append(each['Reversal Indices'].iloc[15:25])
print(rev_ind)

c=[]
for every in rev_ind:
    a = int(max(every))
    b = int(min(every))
    c += [b]
print(c)

# conv = []
# index=[]
# for i in range(len(c)):
#     print((i, c[i]))
#     index += [i]
# print(index)

values_index = c
converted = []
for values in asps:
    converted.append(values['conv'].iloc[0:-1])
print(converted)
```

This is the output:

```
[15    40.0
16    41.0
17    43.0
18    51.0
19    55.0
20    56.0
21    62.0
22    63.0
23    65.0
24    66.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15     62.0
16     63.0
17     67.0
18     74.0
19     78.0
20     80.0
21     86.0
22     88.0
23     96.0
24    102.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15    49.0
16    50.0
17    54.0
18    57.0
19    62.0
20    63.0
21    65.0
22    69.0
23    71.0
24    74.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15    43.0
16    45.0
17    48.0
18    52.0
19    54.0
20    56.0
21    58.0
22    73.0
23    81.0
24    85.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15     64.0
16     66.0
17     78.0
18     82.0
19     89.0
20     93.0
21     94.0
22     96.0
23    103.0
24    105.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15    58.0
16    63.0
17    65.0
18    67.0
19    69.0
20    71.0
21    74.0
22    81.0
23    87.0
24    88.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15    41.0
16    43.0
17    47.0
18    52.0
19    54.0
20    59.0
21    64.0
22    66.0
23    69.0
24    73.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15     73.0
16     77.0
17     79.0
18     80.0
19     82.0
20     83.0
21     85.0
22     92.0
23     96.0
24    100.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15    54.0
16    57.0
17    59.0
18    60.0
19    67.0
20    69.0
21    73.0
22    74.0
23    76.0
24    78.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64, 15    47.0
16    51.0
17    54.0
18    57.0
19    66.0
20    68.0
21    70.0
22    77.0
23    79.0
24    80.0
Name: Reversal Indices, dtype: float64]
[40, 62, 49, 43, 64, 58, 41, 73, 54, 47]

[0     1
1     1
2     1
3     0
4     1
     ..
61    1
62    1
63    0
64    1
65    1
Name: conv, Length: 66, dtype: int64, 0      1
1      1
2      1
3      0
4      0
      ..
98     1
99     1
100    1
101    1
102    1
Name: conv, Length: 103, dtype: int64, 0     1
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
     ..
69    0
70    1
71    1
72    1
73    1
Name: conv, Length: 74, dtype: int64, 0     1
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     1
     ..
80    1
81    1
82    1
83    1
84    1
Name: conv, Length: 85, dtype: int64, 0      0
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
      ..
100    1
101    1
102    1
103    0
104    1
Name: conv, Length: 105, dtype: int64, 0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
     ..
83    0
84    1
85    0
86    1
87    1
Name: conv, Length: 88, dtype: int64, 0     1
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     1
     ..
66    1
67    1
68    0
69    1
70    0
Name: conv, Length: 71, dtype: int64, 0     1
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     1
     ..
95    1
96    1
97    1
98    1
99    1
Name: conv, Length: 100, dtype: int64, 0     1
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     1
     ..
73    1
74    0
75    1
76    1
77    1
Name: conv, Length: 78, dtype: int64, 0     1
1     1
2     0
3     1
4     1
     ..
83    1
84    1
85    1
86    0
87    1
Name: conv, Length: 88, dtype: int64]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
If I interpret the issue description correctly the built in zip() function
may meet the objective.
"""

converted = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
value_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

desired_relationship = zip(value_index,converted)

for relationship in desired_relationship:
    print(relationship)
```

Output

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(4, 'd')
(5, 'e')
(6, 'f')
```